# Activity screen displays after entire code is executed

Tags: android, android-activity

I've designed a code that sends file from android mobile to PC. The code runs absolutely fine , however there is a problem that activity screen displays after entire code has executed.

I wanted to add button to pause or stop transfer. However, even the button is displayed after entire transfer is done.
I've also tried using sleep after `setContentView`() but that doesn't solve my problem.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    status=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.status);
        int x;
DatagramSocket s = new DatagramSocket(2436);

        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("//sdcard//output.3gp");
        while(true)
        {
            b2=new byte[100];
            x=fis.read(b2);

            if(x<=0)
            {
                b2=new byte[10];
                p3=new DatagramPacket(b2,b2.length,client_ip,client_port);
                s.send(p3);
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                p3=new DatagramPacket(b2,b2.length,client_ip,client_port);
                s.send(p3);
                //status.append(b2[0]+" "+p3.getLength());
            }

        }

        fis.close();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't do long tasks from main thread. That will block UI. Move your long tasks to another threads.

Use an AsyncTask. Look at this: http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html

Answer (score 4):

do your file processing task in thread / add your file processing code in onstart method after `super.onStart` called

Comment: 1-Actually, i'm making some layout changes too during my file processing code so making a new thread won't help(since we can't modify main layout in a thread).
2-i tried writing code in onStart() that doesn't help either !